# Simulate location on the iPhone without being linked to the computer

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location

I am working on a navigation app. I used the XCode/iPhone simulator location simulation to simulate driving in various areas.

I now need to demonstrate the app at various events, and I can not have the phone (physically) tied to the computer when doing the demo (I need the port to plug in another device).

Anybody knows a way to wirelessly simulate the location?

The best option I can think of right now is to include some demo code that simulate driving around, is there any known solution that has already implemented that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few months back i've used this project:
https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator

Hope still works for iOS6, give it a try.

Comment: Does this create "original" calls of `didUpdateToLocation` or does this wrap with something similar to "ftdidUpdateToLocation"

Comment: let me give that a try and report back